# Error while sorting java object using comparator: Abstract and does not override abstract method compare

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I want to sort the list of Data object according to roll number. But the following code is not workinh with the comparatoe.

Error:

```
prog.java:15: error: GFG is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Data,Data) in Comparator
class GFG implements Comparator<Data> {
^
prog.java:25: error: <anonymous GFG$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Data,Data) in Comparator
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Data>(){
                                                     ^
prog.java:27: error: compare(Data,Data) in <anonymous GFG$1> cannot implement compare(T,T) in Comparator
            public String compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
                          ^
  return type String is not compatible with int
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparator
prog.java:26: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
            @Override
            ^
prog.java:28: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
                return o1.rollNumber.compareTo(o2.rollNumber);
                                              ^
5 errors
```

Data class -

```
class Data {
    String name;
    String rollNumber;
    Data(String name, String rollNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }
}
```

Main finction -

```
class GFG implements Comparator<Data> {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>();
        list.add(new Data("Harshit","16ume017"));
        list.add(new Data("Neha","16ume08"));
        list.add(new Data("Akshit","16ucc017"));
        list.add(new Data("Kshitiz","16ucs017"));

        System.out.println("Without sorted: \n"+list+"\n");

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Data>(){
            @Override
            public String compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
                return o1.rollNumber.compareTo(o2.rollNumber);
            }
        });

        System.out.println("With sorted: \n"+list+"\n");


    }
}
```

Link to the code(ide): https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/eWws4NwIXU

Comment: `compare` return an int and you don't need to explicitely annotate. Also Why do you need Comparator there? you could just do `(data1, data2) -> o1.rollNumber.compareTo(o2.rollNumber)` Also why your GFG implements Comparator? Remove that implements clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method return `int` not `String`

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Data>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
        return o1.rollNumber.compareTo(o2.rollNumber);
    }
});
```

or (Java 8+)

```
Collections.sort(list, (d1, d2) -> d1.rollNumber.compareTo(d2.rollNumber));
```